# How do I get rid of this error on prisma?

Tags: typescript, next.js, typeerror, prisma

I'm trying to deploy my website but I have this error (which I do not have on local) :

```
Type error: Type '{ title: any; price: any; content: any; author: { connect: { email: string; }; }; }' is not assignable to type '(Without<PostCreateInput, PostUncheckedCreateInput> & PostUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...> & PostCreateInput)'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'price' does not exist in type '(Without<PostCreateInput, PostUncheckedCreateInput> & PostUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...> & PostCreateInput)'.
```

Here is the file `index.ts`:

```
export default async function handle(req, res) {
  const { title, content, price } = req.body;

  const session = await getSession({ req });
  const result = await prisma.post.create({
    data: {
      title: title,
      price: price,
      content: content,
      author: { connect: { email: session?.user?.email } },
    },
  });
  res.json(result);
}
```

And my `schema.prisma` :

```
model Post {
  id        String  @id @default(cuid())
  title     String
  content   String?
  price     String
  published Boolean @default(false)
  author    User?   @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId  String?
}
```

My stack : NextJS 13.2.3
Prisma : 4.11.0,

Can someone please explain me what I'm doing wrong here ?

Thanks in advance.

For now I've tried nothing since I don't understand the error, the code works in local.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answer. In fact I did run npx prisma generate and it returned the table just fine with the "price" row. And here is the code on my create input :

Thanks for the answer. In fact I did run npx prisma generate and it returned the table just fine with the "price" row. And here is the code on my create input :

```js
const Draft: React.FC = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");

  const submitData = async (e: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const body = { title, content, price };
      await fetch("api/post", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
      });
      await Router.push("/drafts");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Did you run "npx prisma generate" after you added the price in your Post model? If you make changes in your model, you need to generate the types or push those changes to the database with "npx prisma migrate dev" (or "npx prisma migrate deploy" on production)

Comment: Can you provide the content of `PostCreateInput` from your deployed codebase ? As @SlothOverlord mentioned, the price property doesn't seem to exist in the generated input-file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited my question so you can see the rest.